# jCarousel - How to set your carousel to fluid width?

Tags: css, jquery-plugins

One of the websites I work on has a few jCarousel sliders each inside their own accordion boxes. ( Click the coloured bar to open a section to see the horizontal carousel )
http://mememotion.tv/

Problem: When you resize the browser window smaller, then larger again, something happens to the css. The videos are now pushed up against each other in a vertical style.

Is there anything css wise i can do to make sure the look of the horizontal pane are kept even if the browser window is resized.

Site Spec:
 - jCarousel
 - Wordpress 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears it's the `<ul class="jcarousel-list jcarousel-list-horizontal">` width which change to 240px while it must keep > 3000px.
You can fix it using `.jcarousel-list.jcarousel-list-horizontal { width:3000px !important;}` but it's not very clean...

I think it's more a problem with JCarousel.

Comment: Hey MatTheCat, thanks for the info.  That css fix worked with some of the panels only.  We have some panels that start off on 4000px.  Setting that to a width of 3000px messes up that styling.  Im looking at a way of setting the ul panel to a set size and keep it at the var that first loads on the page